# Need to split text from numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, split

I have an Excel sheet with column H containing IDs. Unfortunately some people put their IDs to be two letters then 5 numbers (AB12345) and some just put the 5 numbers (12345). I need to go through the whole column and split any entry with letters, so I eventually have a column with all of them being just the 5 numbers.

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/strip-non-numeric-characters

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/659-excel-remove-alpha-characters.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=7,RIGHT(A1,5),A1)
```

and copy down

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know where the alphanumeric characters are in the string, you could use this array formula to get just the numeric portion.

```
=TEXTJOIN("", TRUE, IFERROR(MID(A1, ROW(INDIRECT("1:100")), 1) + 0, ""))
```

You will have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> this formula to get it to be an array formula. That will add curly brackets.
Textjoin is only available in Excel 2016 or [Office 365](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_365).